# Constructor overload contains already defines a member with the same signature

Tags: c#, constructor, overloading

```
public Module(string a, object obj) : this(a, null, obj) { }

public Module(string b, object obj) : this(null, b, obj) { }
```

These constructor overloads do not work

> 'already defines a member with same parameter types'

I have looked around and realise that I cannot do this in c# but can anyone suggest a way around this?

Edit: Thanks for answers.

In this case I have decided that to go with this for now:

```
public Module(string a, object obj) : this(a, null, obj) { }

public Module(string a, string b, object obj) : this(a, b, obj) {}
```

So users will have to include a if they want to use b... not brilliant but there you go

Comment: You mean, each doesn't work separately (then please provide other constructors definitions) or they don't work together (then it's normal, they have exactly same parameters so your program won't know which one it has to use)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter names are meaningless in the context of overloads. I can see what you are trying to do, but I'm not sure why. I would dispense with it entirely:

```
public Module(string a, string b, object obj){}
```

Then call the `Module` constructor, passing in `null` values as appropriate.

```
Module m = new Module(null, "hi", obj);

Module m2 = new Module("bye", null, obj);
```

Comment: thanks for answer andrew. maybe its bad design but i have somehow wound up at this point and there appears to be no other way!

Comment: @Tyler well, I hope you don't mean that you have to do what's in your question, because that's impossible. Both of those constructor signatures are *exactly* the same; the name of the parameters is meaningless.

Comment: No but I have ended up with a class constructor that take these parameters and wanted to be able to overload these but now realise I can't. Oh well

Answer (score 4):

personally i use optional arguments:

```
public Module(object obj, string a = null,string b = null) : this(a, b, obj) { }
```

Heres an article on what they are and how to use them, Note though they are only avaliable in VS2010 (they are part of the compiler not the language so they are available in .net 3.5 as well as 4.0) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: I have done that in the past but am presently working with stylecop and cannot do that!

Answer (score 0):

It's just not possible. You should remove those two constructor overloads.

However, you could work with static factory methods instead. Make sure to use clear names to convey the difference to the API consumer.

```
static Module CreateA(string a, object o) { return new Module(a, null, o); }
static Module CreateB(string b, object o) { return new Module(null, b, o); }
```